# Calculating the value of multiple rows in a column from one table into an other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "opportunties" and "items".
Each opportunities is unique. "items" and "opportunities" are connected by the "opportunitiesid". Therefore can one "opportunities" be connected to multiple "items"
"opportunties" has two colums:  "opportuntiesid" and "potential". "opportuntiesid" is the unique id for "opportunities".
"items" has three colums: "itemsid" which is the unique id for items. "opportuntiesid" which is the id from opportunities. Connecting the items with the opportunities. And "value" which contains an integer value.

What I want to is the following:
Fill the "potential" from "opportunities" with "value" from "items" based on the "opportunitiesid".

What I tried:

```
update opportunities,items
set  opportunties.potential = opportunties.potential + items.value
where  opportunties.opportunitiesid=items.opportuntiesid;
```

this only fills opportunities.potential with the item value from the first item.

Then I tried to do it in two steps:
 first:

```
update opportunities,items
set  opportunties.potential = opportunties.potential + items.value
where  opportunties.opportunitiesid=items.opportuntiesid;
```

and then:

```
update opportunities,items
set  opportunties.potential = opportunties.potential + items.value
where  opportunties.opportunitiesid=items.opportuntiesid 
and where opportunties.potential != items.value;
```

This did not work because some items have the same value.

I don't understand why my update does not work.

Should something still be unclear please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to sum all values from items, and add then to opportunities.potential, since something other does not make sense - if one opportunity X has many items (for example 1,2,3), then how one can update **one** opportunity's potential with **many** values ? 
Only a sum makes sense for me.

If I'am right, then try a dependent (correlated) subquery:

```
update opportunities
    set  opportunties.potential = opportunties.potential + (
        SELECT SUM ( items.value ) FROM items
        WHERE  opportunties.opportunitiesid=items.opportuntiesid
    );
```

and a multitable version  - on MySql this one will probably be faster as the above one, since MySql (as I know) doesn't know how to optimize dependent subqueries by rewriting them into joins, esspecially in updates

```
UPDATE opportunities,
  (
     SELECT opportunitiesid, SUM( value ) as val
     FROM items
     GROUP BY opportunitiesid
) x
SET opportunities = opportunities + x.val
WHERE x.opportunitiesid = opportunities.opportunitiesid
```